# mongo: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: mongodb, installation, shared-libraries

I get this error when I try to run mongo, in ubuntu.

```
mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I upgraded to Karmic yesterday. I have installed mongodb-stable from the repo mentioned [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages). I tried to apt-get libboost, but there is no such package as libboost_thread. I also posted on mongodb-user, but I need a quicker reply, and hence I am posting here. The boost libraries I have are version 1.38. Ask if you need any other help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `libboost-thread1.34.1`